# Is there any simpler way to check the strong level of password?

Tags: python

So i found out this following code used to check the strong level of password.
I was kind of confused about the part: `score = len([x for x in password_strength.values() if x])`
I know that it was used to count value appeared in 'password' but the syntax is strange to me.
And i'm wondering if this is the simplest way.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re



def password():
    print ('Enter a password\n\nThe password must be between 6 and 12 characters.\n')

    while True:
        password = input('Password: ... ')
        if 6 <= len(password) < 12:
            break
        print ('The password must be between 6 and 12 characters.\n')

    password_scores = {0:'Horrible', 1:'Weak', 2:'Medium', 3:'Strong'}
    password_strength = dict.fromkeys(['has_upper', 'has_lower', 'has_num'], False)
    if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
        password_strength['has_upper'] = True
    if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
        password_strength['has_lower'] = True
    if re.search(r'[0-9]', password):
        password_strength['has_num'] = True

    score = len([x for x in password_strength.values() if x])

    print ('Password is %s' % password_scores[score])
password()
```

Comment: Why would you limit the password length to 11 characters?

Comment: This is just for test, i didn't think about that. But i guess i can edit that password length's value later.

Comment: That algorithm is extremely dumb. `Aa0` is strong while `].^~>(+&*}%` is horrible.

Comment: "The password must be between 6 and 12 characters" - simple answer: yes it's very easy to check in this case: the code doesn't support strong passwords.

Comment: You're right. So how to refine that?

Comment: Writing a good strength checker isn't easy. You'll need to detect various patters humans like to use.

Comment: require at least 10 characters and ... That's it. Just require a long password.

Comment: The only way to create strong passwords is to make them long. A 12 character password is weak. A 15 character one is stronger; a 40 character one is very strong. Worrying about patterns is a distraction and can end up giving a false sense of security. Oh and never, ever impose a maximum length to passwords: that often points to weak storage of the passwords.

Comment: @ratchetfreak "require at least 10 characters". From a technical perspective I understand but from a business perspective that's a really bad idea..

Answer (score 5):

Estimating password strength isn't a simple problem. You need to recognize common patterns humans like to use in passwords (words, keyboard-patterns, etc.). For example [dropbox's estimator zxcvbn](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) is pretty advanced. You should consider using an existing estimator library.

---

As a super simple approximation I'd recommend:

```
Base-2-Logarithm(distinct-characters-in-password + 1) * password-length
```

- `Base-2-Logarithm(alphabet-size) * password-length` computes the shannon entropy of a password in bits, assuming each character is chosen independently from a set of size `alphabet-size` with equal probability.
- I use the number of distinct characters in the password plus one as an approximation for the set of characters the user chose from. The `+ 1` ensures that the logarithm doesn't return `-infinity` when working on an empty password.
- You could give a few bonus points to `alphabet-size` for choosing characters from different character classes (uppercase, lowercase, digits, other), but it's probably not worth the bother.

This algorithm has the property that password length is most important for password strength and increased alphabet size shows diminishing returns after a certain point. It is certainly not perfect (e.g. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` is considered very strong), but probably as good as a simple formula will get.

Choose different thresholds for strength name, depending on your rate limiting, hash algorithm and security requirements. For example you could use:

0 - 14 => horrible
15 - 29 => weak
30 - 49 => medium
50 +    => strong

---

**C# code:**

```csharp
alphabetSize = 1 + password.Distinct().Count(); 
strength = Math.Log(alphabetSize, 2) * Password.Length;
```

**Python code:**

```
alphabetSize = len(set(password)) + 1
strength = math.log2(alphabetSize) * len(password)
```

Comment: Seems good, apart from not being Python :-)

Comment: What sort of algorithm would `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` recognize as weak?  One that takes into account consecutive letters?  Seems like a very specific edge case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey zxcvbn, which I recommended above [recognizes it as a "sequence"](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html). It also recognizes repeated characters, dictionary words and keyboard patterns (its name is a keyboard pattern).